# Hagamos [aplicación-web] sinónimo de [aplicacion-web]

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

[aplicación-web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicaci%c3%b3n-web) tiene mas de 100 preguntas, mientras que [aplicacion-web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicacion-web) cuenta con sólo 6 preguntas.

Nótese que la primera lleva acento, mientras que la segunda no.

Comment: Sugiero que [tag:aplicacion-web] (sin acento) debe ser quemada y esas 6 preguntas editadas con la etiqueta correcta. No tiene sentido tener ambas.

Comment: @Flxtr: El quemado de etiquetas se reserva para las etiquetas que son realmente malas. En este caso la etiquetas en cuestión no son malas, sino que son prácticamente idénticas. Más detalles en [What does it mean to “burninate” a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/289691)

Comment: bueno, partamos del hecho, ¿qué diferencia existe entre [tag:aplicación-web] y [tag:aplicacion-web]?

Comment: @Flxtr ¿Es pregunta retórica?

Comment: jejeje no, no es una pregunta retórica :)

Comment: @Flxtr No entiendo la pregunta

Comment: bien, me refiero a que cuando son etiquetas sinónimas es porque son casi iguales, pero difieren de algo, por ejemplo, [tag:aplicación-web] sería sinónimo de [tag:web-application] esto porque ésta última viene del sitio padre SO. Considero que el caso de [tag:aplicacion-web] no tiene sentido dado que es exactactamente lo mismo que [tag:aplicación-web], incluso hasta con faltas de ortgrafía.

Comment: @Flxtr: En cuanto a "es exactamente los mismo" eso se resuelve con hacer sinónimo :)

Comment: ¿Y si las reetiquetamos a mano? Siendo sólo 6, no crearía tanto bump, y esperaríamos a que se elimine automáticamente.

Comment: @Mariano: Me parece que reaparecería por error de ortografía/hábitos. Podemos intentarlo y esperar a ver que pasa. ¿Cambiamos la etiqueta de   esta pregunta de `soporte` a `discusión`?

Comment: @Rubén Pensaba que haría saltar al filtro "*es muy parecida a otra etiqueta*", pero es cierto que sino no se hubiese creado en primer lugar. No la usé jamás, ni sigo la etiqueta, pero confío en tu experiencia y criterio para determinar que es lo más adecuado.

Comment: @Rubén No creo que haga falta plantear discusión sobre temas así... Se resuelven con 2 clicks y no hay ninguna contra en generarlo

Comment: @Mariano: Cometí un error, agregué la etiqueta `aplicación-web` a algunas preguntas con la etiqueta `aplicacion-web` sin retirar esta última. Espero que no se tome a mal. Voy a esperar un poco antes de proceder a volver a editarlas.

Comment: @Rubén Yo hice lo mismo con las que usé para duplicados... Tienen ambas etiquetas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he creado el sinónimo:

> [aplicación-web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicaci%c3%b3n-web) (etiqueta maestra) - [aplicacion-web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicacion-web)