# ¿Qué hacer con las etiquetas [concatenación] y [concatenacion]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Quiero que fusionen las etiquetas [concatenación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concatenaci%c3%b3n) y [concatenacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concatenacion).

Noten que la primera tiene tilde en la letra **o** y la segunda no.

Es decir, con fusionarlas me refiero a hacer un sinónimo de etiquetas.

Otra alternativa que me dijo [*@Phi*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16841/phi?tab=topactivity) es quemar las dos etiquetas y además quemar [concat](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concat), debido a su poco uso. Quisiera la opinión de todos. ¿Qué hay que hacer con estas etiquetas?

Cuando yo era moderador hice un sinónimo similar.

- [Hagamos [aplicación-web] sinónimo de [aplicacion-web]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1768/hagamos-aplicacion-web-sin%c3%b3nimo-de-aplicaci%c3%b3n-web)

Comment: Busqué las preguntas que tienen tilde y hay 7 al momento, y las que no tienen tilde no hay ninguna. Considero que `concatenación` no es una etiqueta con orioentación de uso principal y deber ser eliminada de la faz de la tierra

Comment: @Phi También habría que pensar en la etiqueta [tag:concat]

Comment: Aplicaría el mismo caso con [concat](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concat), al momento hay 9 preguntas y no tiene orientación de uso principal o muy específica a una única tecnología ;)

Comment: Las etiquetas con poco uso no son problema ¿o sí?. En cualquier caso, véase [¿Cuál es el proceso para eliminar las etiquetas (quemarlas)?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2839/65)

Comment: @Rubén No creo que sean un problema, pero según el comentario de Phi. Hay varios cuestionamientos, ¿La etiqueta tiene orientación de uso principal? ¿Las etiquetas sin orientación de uso principal deben ser quemadas? ¿Qué significa principal?

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta está "rara". Originalmente el título era quemar, ahora es fusionar, pero continua con la etiqueta de solicitud de quemado y tiene la etiqueta sinónimos de etiqueta. ¿Que tal si mientras se discute el asunto le quitamos las etiquetas mencionadas, agregamos [meta-tag:etiquetas] y cambiamos el título a algo así como *¿Qué hacer con ...?* ?

Comment: @Rubén Listo, quité las dos y puse etiquetas y título editado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya se mencionó en comentarios, las tres etiquetas en cuestión tienen menos de 10 preguntas cada una.

Lo primero sería preguntarnos si estas etiquetas son útiles, y si lo son si significan lo mismo o no.

Entre las dos que sólo varía el acento/tilde, recuerdo que cuando se lanzó el sitio no era posible usar acentos lo cual se corrigió, y como mencionas en algunos casos se hicieron sinónimos poniendo como principal la que lleva acento usando como argumento para ello el uso correcto del español, sin embargo, esto causaba problemas técnicos en las aplicaciones móviles. No recuerdo si ya se resolvieron.

Recapitulando, si tienes especial interés en que haya una etiqueta relativa a "concatenación" y esta se justifica (no es una meta etiqueta, etc.) sugiero mejorar [concatenación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concatenaci%c3%b3n) antes de proceder con el sinónimo, por ejemplo, agregar o refinar la orientación de uso y wiki.

Comment: Si te refieres a este problema [Las etiquetas con tildes se reproducen incorrectamente en la versión móvil cuando se edita una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2221/las-etiquetas-con-tildes-se-reproducen-incorrectamente-en-la-versi%C3%B3n-m%C3%B3vil-cuand). Ya está corregido :)

Comment: @KacosPro Gracias. Ese es uno de varios reportes relacionados con los acentos en la aplicación móvil.

Comment: La etiqueta [tag:concatenacion] ya está quemada. :)